# Ionic Framework in-app storage

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to make an app which has built-in a folder with videos.
The problem is (and searching for few hours aleardy) I can't find the path for the video ("triunghi.mp4").
Here's what I have until now:

[image: ionic framework app storage]

What is wrong or what is the good path I should use?

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following path :

```
/android_asset/www/videos/triunghi.mp4
```

Comment: I have it working as here in this project https://github.com/Microsmsm/math-magic/blob/master/game.html

Comment: I'll try in few hours to see if that it's not because of some permissions that I'll need to put in configuration file.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
This is my project: https://github.com/s1lviu/Educational-Videos

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the [$cordovaFileOpener2](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/) plugin that don't have access into assets directory.

I solved it by copying the videos folder to external place (externalDataDirectory) and open them (the videos) from there.